# Is it possible to use Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aspectj

I am trying to use plugin com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4 in IntelliJ.
But I've got the error

```
Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum
```

The android gradle plugin version 2.3.3 supports Intellij.

I need IntelliJ due to I want to use AspectJ + Java 8 in IDE. Android Studio IDE doesn't support AspectJ yet, only gradle plugin.

Is it possible to use new version Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 with ***exactly IntelliJ***, not Android Studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Android Studio 3.0 features will be merged in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.x which is not released yet, you can't update just Android plug-in separately, since it's a bundled plug-in and the synchronization with Android Studio is performed manually at JetBrains.

You can [track the progress here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181202).

Comment: Thank you. I think you mean IDEA 2017.**3**. IDEA 2017.2 is [avaible](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/05/intellij-idea-2017-2-eap-is-here/). I am using it)

Comment: It's a pre-release, official release is not available yet. AS 3.0 features may be merged later in 2017.2.x updates.

Comment: @Halil sorry, it was postponed to 2017.3.x version, you can [track the progress here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181202).

Comment: 2017.3 is out but I still see this warning!

Comment: @EugenMartynov please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-181202 for updates.

Comment: Looks like they postponed it to 2018.1 again, although they want to backport it to 2017.3.x once 2018.1 was released

Answer (score 12):

As workaround you can add in gradle.properties this option:
`android.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3`

Full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634836/4050911

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that this will get the Gradle sync working in IntelliJ but you'll probably run into issues when trying to deploy your Android app onto a device or emulator from within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you'll have to download [Android Studio 3.0 (Canary)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html) in order to use gradle plugin 3.0.0.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 doesn't support AspectJ:)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You need update your gradle version of both file Module level and Project Level as per the error '3.0.0' and then try to build the project

Comment: When it gradle version was lower(3.3), the error was another: Gradle demanded new gradle verstion for using this plugin.

Comment: @irina Then please try to update Android Studio  I think it will solve your problem

Comment: As far as version Android 3.0. is **alfa** (not even beta), version android gradle plugin is **alfa** too(3.0.0-alfa4), and [maven reposotry](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle) even doesn't show the new version, I think that the new android gradle plugin doesn't supported by Idea yet.

Comment: @Irina  follow this link https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html   Android 3.0 currently Alfa not stable  thats why it is giving you error

Comment: I am using IntelliJ with android plugin:) Not Android Studio. Android Studio works fine, but doesn't support AspectJ.