# Can't use new Android Gradle Plugin with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

When I'm trying to use Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.+ with Intellij IDEA, I'm getting error: `Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum`

But my version of IntelliJ is higher than 2017.2 and it should work with gradle plugin for AS 3.0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It can be fixed by adding this option to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3
```

**Explanation:**

From Reddit /r/androiddev

> A version check is in place in `ModelBuilder` that is fed by Gradle
>   properties inserted by the IDE when you execute the Sync action. The
>   fix is to add the following to gradle.properties:
>   `android.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3`
>
> AS 3.0 is sending the
>   value 3, whereas older versions as well as IntelliJ send 1 or lower,
>   if they send a value at all. Once set as specified, sync works again
>   and everything so far has been operating normally.

[Full answer with comments from Android Studio team](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6c71av/using_android_gradle_plugin_300alpha1_with/)

### UPDATE

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1+ supports Android Gradle Plugin 3.0+!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `android.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3` property in the `gradle.properties` file (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634836/1071320)) will get the Gradle sync working but you may run into issues when trying to deploy your Android app onto a device or emulator from within IntelliJ. For that you'll probably have to use Android Studio 3.x or one of the `install` Gradle tasks... until a version of IntelliJ IDEA is released that supports Android 3.x features (keep an eye on [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181202) JetBrains issue).

Comment: What issues you mean? I use IDEA as main IDE and haven't any issues.

Comment: Mainly the issues I'm seeing are around installing the APK on the device or emulator when trying to run the app or instrumentation tests from IntelliJ. I suspect these issues will be fixed with the release of IDEA 2017.3 (see link in my answer) but in the meanwhile I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am facing the exact same problem with IDEA 2017.3

Comment: I've resorted to using Android Studio until Android Studio 3.0 features are added to IntelliJ. I've updated my answer to link to the JetBrains issue that's open for this.

Comment: @kliron, try to add flag -t to your app Run Configuration in Intellij IDEA

Comment: This flag should be in "Install flags"